# Mask package name in test file only

Tags: unit-testing, go

In pursuit of 100% unit test coverage, we have several lines we're trying to test in one of our functions.  The relevant function calls out to the runtime package:

```
// functionName returns a string representing the function name of the function n stack frames above the caller.
// if n = 0, the name of the function calling functionName() will be returned.
func functionName(n int) string {
    pc, _, _, ok := runtime.Caller(n + 1)
    if !ok {
        return "unknown function"
    }
    me := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
    if me == nil {
        return "unknown function"
    }

    split := strings.Split(me.Name(), ".")
    if len(split) == 0 {
        return "unknown function"
    }
    return split[len(split)-1]
}
```

Specifically, the 3 `if` statements and their return values are currently untested, because the runtime functions don't appear to be easily manipulated to return the values we want.  Our standard response in these cases is to mock out the items in question, but these calls are to package-level functions (rather than methods of an interface) within the runtime package itself.

My first thought was to mock out the runtime token itself by using a structure with Caller() and FuncForPC() methods, assigned to a variable named "runtime" in the test files (so it wouldn't affect the production code flow, since test files are omitted during normal builds).  However, this triggers a build error about "runtime" being redeclared within the (global) block.

I know this would be possible if the "runtime" variable were declare in a non-global scope ([example masking fmt](https://play.golang.org/p/J4ccrIPLfy)), but I can't find an elegant way to do so such that it gets masked within the tests, but not within the production code itself.  The only way I've thought of is by altering the source of the production code to declare such a variable and replacing it's value in the tests, but this is far from ideal, since it complicates the production code purely for the purposes of testing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain why 3 untested lines is a problem? Are you striving for 100% data/state-space coverage too or are you satisfied with 100% source code lines coverage?

Comment: Currently I believe it's only 100% source code coverage.  We're seeking it because the new build guidelines for the company specify 100% unit test coverage as required.  This is rather annoying, frankly, because imo 100% test coverage is a rather unreasonable requirement (there are a noteworthy number of lines that _really_ don't justify being tested).  But them's the breaks.  If what we're looking to do isn't possible without changing the production code, I think we'll just have to accept sub-100%, but I figured I'd ask if there was some way I wasn't seeing to do this.

Comment: Cool! Then you are free to _remove_ the untested lines. If it is more important to have 100% line coverage than properly working code: So be it. If that corporate-policy-mandated-bulshit-code chrashes you can pull out the coverage report and state "We did everything right! Look here 100% coverage! It must be someones else fault. We are sorry."

Comment: God, I wish I could actually get away with that...

Comment: `In pursuit of 100% unit test coverage` -- This is a hollow pursuit. 1) 100% test coverage doesn't really mean anything. 2) Defensive code will have lines that literally _can't_ be covered, because they handle cases that should never happen.

Comment: @Flimzy I fully agree, and our current position seems to be to just accept that those lines can't be covered in tests.  But the new handbook says 100% coverage, so we at least have to make an effort.  I figured if there was some effective way of masking the import, it'd be worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to declare variables of those functions you want to mock.

```
var runtimeCaller = runtime.Caller
var runtimeFuncForPC = runtime.FuncForPC

func functionName(n int) string {
    pc, _, _, ok := runtimeCaller(n + 1)
    if !ok {
        return "unknown function"
    }
    me := runtimeFuncForPC(pc)
    if me == nil {
        return "unknown function"
    }

    split := strings.Split(me.Name(), ".")
    if len(split) == 0 {
        return "unknown function"
    }
    return split[len(split)-1]
}
```

Or if you prefer the dot notation...

```
var _runtime = struct{
    Caller    func(skip int) (pc uintptr, file string, line int, ok bool)
    FuncForPC func(pc uintptr) *runtime.Func
}{runtime.Caller, runtime.FuncForPC}

func functionName(n int) string {
    pc, _, _, ok := _runtime.Caller(n + 1)
    if !ok {
        return "unknown function"
    }
    me := _runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
    if me == nil {
        return "unknown function"
    }

    split := strings.Split(me.Name(), ".")
    if len(split) == 0 {
        return "unknown function"
    }
    return split[len(split)-1]
}
```

And in your tests, before running `functionName`, you can set the variables/fields to mock implementations. And if other tests may cause the `functionName` to be called beware of concurrent access... I don't think there is much else you can do without changing the existing code significantly.

Comment: Ya, we considered doing this, but this would mean changing and complicating the production code purely for the purposes of testing, which we didn't want to do.  Was hoping there was a way of doing it that didn't involved changing the prod file.

Comment: Marking as answer even though we're not going with this solution, since it seems to be the only functional method of doing what I asked.

Comment: I understand, if you and your team find a better solution down the road, please do let me know, I'd definitely be interested because I'm not very fond of this one either.